# SSRS expression divide by zero in rdl

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, rdlc, ssrs-tablix, rdl

How should I handle divide by zero error in `rdl` expression for **SSRS 2017**?

I have tried the below approaches but nothing works.

1.

```
=iif((iif((SUM(Fields!Consumption.Value)/
(iif((Fields!daysINDate.Value)<=0,1,Fields!daysINDate.Value))*30)<=0,0,
(SUM(Fields!Consumption.Value)/
(iif((Fields!daysINDate.Value)<=0,1,Fields!daysINDate.Value))*30)))=0,0,

SUM(Fields!ClosingStock.Value)/(iif((SUM(Fields!Consumption.Value)/
(iif((Fields!daysINDate.Value)<=0,1,Fields!daysINDate.Value))*30)<=0,0,
(SUM(Fields!Consumption.Value)/
(iif((Fields!daysINDate.Value)<=0,1,Fields!daysINDate.Value))*30))))*30)
```

2. (SUM(Fields!ClosingStock.Value)/
   (iif((SUM(Fields!Consumption.Value)/
   (iif(Fields!daysINDate.Value<=0,1,Fields!daysINDate.Value))*30)<=0,0,
   (SUM(Fields!Consumption.Value)/
   (iif(Fields!daysINDate.Value<=0,1,Fields!daysINDate.Value))*30)))*30)

Answer (score 0):

SSRS checks both sides of the IIF statement... if either the THEN or ELSE part if the IIF is 0, it will throw up an error.

One way to get around it is to use VB code.

Right click on your report -> report properties -> code and paste the following code :

```
Public Function NDZ(Byval a As Decimal,Byval b As Decimal, Byval c As Decimal) As Decimal
'  Fix for divide by zero problem in VB
' calculates  a/b  and either returns result or c if b = 0 


if b = 0 then 
    return c 
else 
    return a/b 
end if 

end function
```

Now on your report, enter the following expression in your text box you want to perform the calculation :

```
=code.NDZ(SUM(Fields!Consumption.Value), Fields!daysINDate.Value, 0)
```

so if either Fields!daysINDate.Value or SUM(Fields!Consumption.Value) is 0, then it will return 0 and not an error.

Answer (score 0):

You should only be checking the denominator for zero - not the division operation.

```
=IIF(Fields!daysINDate.Value = 0, 0, SUM(Fields!Consumption.Value))
 /
 IIF(Fields!daysINDate.Value = 0, 1, Fields!daysINDate.Value) 
 *30
```